# How to implement a system that checks whether text entered in the forms follow a set of rules?

Tags: forms, plugins, web-applications

I'm looking for suggestion/direction to implement a rule-based form verification system for a **website that I use daily as a user**. The problem is as follows:

1. We have a web-based system (website) provided by an external party where users (employees at my company) enter several form-fields before putting in orders.
2. In that system, there are some relationships between different fields. For example, if `field A` is entered as `cat`, `field B` must be either `feline` or `felidae`, **nothing else**.
3. Currently, the website allows users to enter anything in those text fields. That means some employees make mistakes and it creates problem when we want to organize and analyze the data.
4. It would be **almost impossible to ask the website developer to implement these rules in their system** (partly because their system is used by other clients--not just our company--and partly because our rules are changing periodically). This means we need to come up with the solution on our (client/user/browser) side.

I'm not even sure where to start (i.e. which approach I should look into) to solve this issue. Would implementing a browser extension/plug-in, which checks the content in all of the form fields when the user clicks submit, solve the problem? Is that even possible? Thank you in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an great use-case for [userscripts](https://github.com/OpenUserJs/OpenUserJS.org/wiki/Userscript-beginners-HOWTO). The following should get you started:

```
(function() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form#someFormID');
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    function abort(message) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(message);
    }
    // <input name="username"> is available as form.username
    if (form.someFieldName.value != 'cat') {
      abort(`${form.someFieldName.name} must be 'cat'!`);
    }
  })
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrea Reina! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a browser extension which will check that on which link user is clicking. If it is that website's link, on which you want to apply form validation then it will validate the form.
For this, first you need to know that which browser they basically use. Then according to that browser, you can make the extension.

If they are using **Google chrome**, here is [simple guide](https://developer.chrome.com/getstarted) to make a extension. You can start with few 
[samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples)
 also. Here is simple [guide](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/) to make an extension for **Mozilla Firefox** .

Comment: Thank you for the direction and sharing the resources, @Prateek!